# Pygame/Python Test between enemies in a list?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pygame

I have a list, containing classes of `enemy` and I've made them follow the player using a `for` loop and a function within the enemy class called `move()`.

But when there are multiple enemies they will get jumbled as they follow the player, and so I decided to add this to the `for` loop:

```
for enmy in enemies:
   pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), (enmy.x-enmy.rad,enmy.y-enmy.rad), enmy.rad, 0)
   for enmy2 in enemies:
       if enmy2 is not enmy:
            if not enmy.rect.colliderect(enmy2.rect):
                enmy.move()
enmy.rect=pygame.Rect(enmy.x-enmy.rad*2,enmy.y-enmy.rad*2,enmy.rad*2,enmy.rad*2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,255), enmy.rect, 2)
```

So I was hoping this would test for every instance in the list besides itself, but when the object is alone it doesn't move! (and also if there are two of them, they collide and just stop)

Here is the whole code (no extra files required c:)

```
import pygame
from random import randint
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

px=35
py=35
prect=pygame.Rect(px-10,py-10,20,20)

class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.rad=randint(5,10)
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(0,0,0,0)
    def move(self):
        if self.x>px:
            self.x-=1
        if self.y<py:
            self.y+=1
        if self.x<px:
            self.x+=1
        if self.y>py:
            self.y-=1

enemies=[Enemy(90,80),Enemy(100,100)]

while True:
    screen.fill((200,230,200))
    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[K_UP]:
        py-=2
    if key[K_DOWN]:
        py+=2
    if key[K_RIGHT]:
        px+=2
    if key[K_LEFT]:
        px-=2

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            exit()

    for enmy in enemies:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), (enmy.x-enmy.rad,enmy.y-enmy.rad), enmy.rad, 0)
        for enmy2 in enemies:
            if enmy2 is not enmy:
                if not enmy.rect.colliderect(enmy2.rect):
                    enmy.move()

        enmy.rect=pygame.Rect(enmy.x-enmy.rad*2,enmy.y-enmy.rad*2,enmy.rad*2,enmy.rad*2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,255), enmy.rect, 2)

    prect=pygame.Rect(px-20,py-20,20,20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,255), (px-10,py-10), 10, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), prect, 2)
    clock.tick(80)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Someone please help me!

Comment: You certainly should correct the `move()` function in class Enemy. You should have `if elif` structure instead of only `if`s. You'll figure out why.

Comment: Is that a speed thing, someone has suggested this before.

Comment: Also, in the `for` loop, you check if the enemies collide, instead you should be checking if the enemies collide after the move!

Comment: Oops, yeah! Accuracy is important!

Comment: No! Not a speeding thing! Say `if self.x>px: self.x-=1` gets triggered, but then, even the next if statement will trigger, i.e. `if self.x<px: self.x+=1`

Comment: When I used elif, the enemies moved in a weird pattern. It is hard to explain, go paste the code and compare for yourself.

Comment: I am sorry, I will try & then comment further.

Comment: What exactly do you want the enemies to do? Roam around randomly, right?

Comment: I want them to follow the player, I thought that part was already working fine.

Comment: Hmm...the enemies seem to hinder themselves, when the 1st one reaches top corner & is about to turn, it cant, because it is colliding with the other one, which itself wants to go top but cant go because there is an enemy there. Think you should distance the enemies & have a concept of direction of the enemy, maybe. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure how to do that though, hence asking this question. Thank you for all of your help though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some deep thinking & fiddling around, (playing too), I managed to do the following...

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

px=35
py=35
prect=pygame.Rect(px-10,py-10,20,20)

class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.rad=random.randint(5,10)
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(0,0,0,0)
        self.x_dir = random.choice(('left','right'))
        self.y_dir = random.choice(('up','down'))
    def move(self, mode='chase'):
        if mode=='chase':
            if self.x>px:
                self.x-=1
            elif self.x<px:
                self.x+=1
            if self.y<py:
                self.y+=1
            elif self.y>py:
                self.y-=1
        else: # roam around
            # Move for x direction
            if self.x_dir == 'left':
                if self.x > 1:
                    self.x -= 1
                else:
                    self.x_dir = 'right'
                    self.x += 1
            else:
                if self.x < px - 1:
                    self.x += 1
                else:
                    self.x_dir = 'left'
                    self.x -= 1
            # Now move for y direction
            if self.y_dir == 'up':
                if self.y > 1:
                    self.y -= 1
                else:
                    self.y_dir = 'down'
                    self.y += 1
            else:
                if self.y < py - 1:
                    self.y += 1
                else:
                    self.y_dir = 'up'
                    self.y -= 1


enemies=[Enemy(50,60),Enemy(200,100), Enemy(200,400), Enemy(200,200), Enemy(200,400), Enemy(200,200)]
roam = {} # Dict to track relative roam/chase
roam_count = {} # Dict to track time for which roaming
max_roam = {}
max_chasing = len(enemies) // 3
cur_chasing = 0
for i, enmy in enumerate(enemies):
    if cur_chasing < max_chasing:
        roam[i] = 'chase'
        cur_chasing += 1
    else:
        roam[i] = 'roam'
    roam_count[i] = 0
    max_roam[i] = random.randint(100, 500)

while True:
    screen.fill((200,230,200))
    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[K_UP]:
        py-=2
    if key[K_DOWN]:
        py+=2
    if key[K_RIGHT]:
        px+=2
    if key[K_LEFT]:
        px-=2

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            exit()

    prect=pygame.Rect(px-20,py-20,20,20)

    for e_1, enmy in enumerate(enemies):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), (enmy.x-enmy.rad,enmy.y-enmy.rad), enmy.rad, 0)
        moved_once = False
        for e_2, enmy2 in enumerate(enemies):
            if enmy2 is not enmy:
                if enmy.rect.colliderect(enmy2.rect):
                    if roam[e_2] == roam[e_1] == 'roam':
                        if cur_chasing < max_chasing:
                            roam[e_1] = 'chase'
                    elif roam[e_2] == roam[e_1] == 'chase':
                        roam[e_2] = 'roam'
                        cur_chasing -= 1
                    if roam[e_1] == 'roam':
                        roam_count[e_1] += 1
                        enmy.move('roam')
                        if roam_count[e_1] > max_roam[e_1]:
                            roam_count[e_1] = 0
                            if cur_chasing < max_chasing:
                                roam[e_1] = 'chase'
                    else:
                        enmy.move('chase')
                else:
                    if not moved_once:
                        if roam[e_1] == 'roam':
                            roam_count[e_1] += 1
                            enmy.move('roam')
                            if roam_count[e_1] > max_roam[e_1]:
                                roam_count[e_1] = 0
                                if cur_chasing < max_chasing:
                                    roam[e_1] = 'chase'
                        else:
                            enmy.move('chase')
                        moved_once = True


        enmy.rect=pygame.Rect(enmy.x-enmy.rad*2,enmy.y-enmy.rad*2,enmy.rad*2,enmy.rad*2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,255), enmy.rect, 2)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,255), (px-10,py-10), 10, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), prect, 2)
    clock.tick(80)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I have commented at various places. Hope you get the gist & maybe some idea from this.

Comment: Can't wait to try this out! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've started solving the collision issues with multiple `Group`s, as there are hooks in PyGame that make this kind of thing pretty straightforward.

Par example: a simple game -- say, a space shooter with no objects besides good guys, bad guys, and their respective projectiles -- might use one 'master group' for updating, then compare 'good group' against 'bad group' to see who's hitting who.

```
all_queue = pygame.sprite.Group()
good_queue = pygame.sprite.Group()
bad_queue = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Then at the correct moment in your loop, call something to the effect of the following:

```
…##fancy and engaging code above
all_queue.update() ##will call every update() for all sprites within, if you're using sprite.update()
dict_of_hits = pygame.sprite.collidegroup(good_queue, bad_queue, False, False)
```

This nets you a `dict` named dict_of_hits which will use the contents of good_queue as keys and any sprites they've collided with from bad_queue as the subsequent values. You can handle them as you see fit. I find this to be the simplest way to handle issues like avoiding 'friendly fire' checks; just put good-guy bullets in the good-queue and 'bad-guy bullets' in the bad-queue, then compare them and see who's hitting who. The `False, False` bit tells PyGame not to automatically call `self.kill` on each thing it finds.

Additionally, there's the ever-popular `spritecollide` which can be used in iteration. It compares a single sprite against a `Group` and returns a `list` of hits.

```
all_queue.update()
for good_sprite in good_queue:
    hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(good_sprite, bad_queue, False)
```

One good thing about the latter is the 'if not results: pass' effect. In other words if nothing comes back, the iterations are over! No need to call `colliderect` on everything in an enumerated loop; you have the total list of things that are assuredly colliding with either a whole `Group` of sprites, or a single sprite! This is a good way to keep yourself from brute-forcing your way through collision detection and iterating over every sprite in the queue.

```
for sprite in some_queue:
    hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, some_other_queue, False)
    if hit_list:
        ##start killing guys, assigning points, changing momentum, etc
```